# recv() end of line

Tags: c, recv, eol

```
while ((client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &c, (socklen_t *) &clientlength)) > 0)
{
  int h = 0; 
  int i = 0;
  char el[4] = "\r\n\r\n";

  while (recv(client, r , 1, 0) != 0)
  {
    if (h==4) 
      break;

    if (*r == el[h])
    {
      h++;
    }

    *r++;
    i++;
  }
}
```

This is a server program and I'm using `recv()` to receive the input request from client side.

I used `"\r\n\r\n"` to indicate end of line which means that on the client side, after they type some input, they have to press Enter twice in order to send the message.

But when I ran my program with this while loop, the client actually have to press Enter three times for the message to pass, why is it like this and how do i fix it so that i would only  have to press Enter twice?

Comment: OT: Your are missing to test the result of `recv()` for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move h==4 check down as below

```
    if(*r==el[h]){
    h++;
    }

    r++;
    i++;

    if (h==4) break;
```